# ImportError: cannot import name NO_DEFAULT

Tags: python, django, importerror, optparse

I'm trying to run a Django site's `manage.py` script, but it fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_manager
  File "/scratch/tools/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from optparse import OptionParser, NO_DEFAULT
ImportError: cannot import name NO_DEFAULT
```

This happens regardless of whether I use Python 2.5.1 or 2.6.1 (Fedora packages). I can reproduce the error when doing the import in an interactive Python session.

This is not very surprising, considering that `NO_DEFAULT` is not listed in `optparse.py`'s `__all__` and is also not listed in the [`optparse` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html).

What is surprising, then, is that on my own workstation I can successfully do `from optparse import NO_DEFAULT` in both Python 2.5.5 and 2.6.6 (Debian packages).

My question is twofold:

- How can it be that I can import something that is not listed in `__all__`?
- How should I fix the Django `manage.py`? I want it to work with Python 2.5, if at all possible.

Comment: If you look at the source of `optparse` (probably in `"...Python26/lib/optparse.py"`), do you see a difference between on your local machine and your server? Is `NO_DEFAULT` defined in the version on the server?

Comment: BTW `__all__` is only (afaik) used for `from whatever import *`; if you name the variables instead of using *-imports you can get anything that is defined in the namespace of the module.

Comment: The source is for `optparse.py` is slightly different between my workstation and the server, but `__all__` is the same and so is `NO_DEFAULT`. (So is the version number, strangely enough.) I'm doing `from optparse import` in all cases.

Comment: There is `NO_DEFAULT` declared in `optparse.py` [since 2.3](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release23-maint/Lib/optparse.py?view=markup) (line 306). It's something wrong with your Python installation.

Comment: @DrTyrsa: `NO_DEFAULT` is in my `optparse.py`, all versions of it.

Comment: @larsmans That means there is something wrong with it. Change it to correct version somehow (manually or by reinstalling Python).

Comment: @larsmans: my guess is that your Python is resolving `optparse` to the wrong file. Are there any other `optparse.py`s lying around? If you call `inspect.getsource` on the module object, does it give the file you think it should?

Comment: @katrielalex: you're right, the error is resolved by unsetting `PYTHONPATH`, so there's a stale `optparse.py` somewhere that `locate` didn't dig up for some reason. If you can also explain how `from optparse import NO_DEFAULT` works when `NO_DEFAULT` is not listed in `__all__`, I'll accept your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always in Python, `__all__` is more of a guideline than a rule. It comes about because of the we-love-to-hate-it `*-import`, described in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html) as

> If the list of identifiers is replaced by a star ('*'), all public
>   names defined in the module are bound in the local namespace of the
>   `import` statement.

There is an immediate technical difficulty here: how should the interpreter know what the public names of a module are? There is a convention that any name in a module not beginning with an `_` is public; you might think that as a first approximation one should simply import all such names in the module's namespace. Unfortunately, this becomes more complicated when you introduce packages, because then computing the public names becomes a large task involving various imports, path rewrites, file reads, and what have you. This is not a good thing. Thus, the simplifying decision was taken to allow the module author to specify exactly which names in the package should be imported from a *-import, by defining `__all__` in the module.

But if you don't *-import -- if you give the interpreter the name of the variable you want to import -- then it doesn't need to worry about finding all the global names, so it can ignore `__all__` and just look up the name in the module's namespace.

That does mean that `__all__` may not be the same as the subset of `locals().keys()` not starting with an underscore. In particular, there may be perfectly good objects in the module which are not exported by *-imports. This is what happens with `NO_DEFAULT`.